# Sort Data in a column based on time interval using R

Tags: r, sorting, time-series, rstudio, strptime

I am new to R programming and I would appreciate any help I can get. I am working with event data and I am trying to sort the events based on a single date/time column in order to see how events developed over time. Thus first I want to sort the events based on time intervals of one hr and days and then plot how many events occurred throughout the days. But I do not know how to start such code

My date/time column is in the following format:

```
          Timestamp
2010-02-12 15:08:10
2010-02-12 15:13:29
2010-02-12 15:09:04
2010-02-13 16:08:07
```

Thank you

Comment: So what do you expect as a result from that?

Comment: As a result I expect to see how many events occured in a given hour and the patter of do these events decrease or increase over time. So i will be plotting the time and date on x axis and number of occurrences on Y